# SQL Loader Error 350

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, sql-loader, ora-01461

I'm trying to load an .xml datafile into oracle for the last couple of hours without success.

======Here is my .ctl file====

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE output.xml "STR '</article>'"
BADFILE output.BAD
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE FERNANDO.ARTICLES
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
dummy filler terminated by "article>",
articlesTitle VARCHAR(500) enclosed by "<title>" and "</title>",
articlesAuthor CHAR(100) enclosed by "<author>" and "</author>",
articlesText CHAR(50000) enclosed by "<text>" and "</text>",
articlesClient CHAR(50) enclosed by "<client>" and "</client>",
articlesCharset CHAR(50) enclosed by "<charset>" and "</charset>",
articlesHeaders  CHAR(5000) enclosed by "<headers>" and "</headers>",
articlesTransferEncoding CHAR(50) enclosed by "{Transfer-encoding=" and ", ",
articlesCacheControl CHAR(50) enclosed by "Cache-control=" and ", ",
articlesContentType CHAR(500) enclosed by "Content-type=" and ", ",
articlesPostedDate CHAR(50) enclosed by "Date=" and ", ",
articlesExpireDate CHAR(50) enclosed by "Expires=" and ", ",
articlesSetCookie CHAR(500) enclosed by "Set-cookie=" and ", ",
articlesDomain CHAR(50) enclosed by "Domain=" and ", ",
articlesServer CHAR(200) enclosed by "Server=" and ", ",
articlesPragma CHAR(200) enclosed by "Pragma=" and ", "
)
```

However, I have the following error at every other row:

```
Record 10: Rejected - Error on table FERNANDO.ARTICLES.
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

The Article Table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTICLES (
    articlesTitle        VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ,
    articlesAuthor       VARCHAR2(64) NULL ,
    articlesText         VARCHAR2(1024) NULL ,
    articlesClient       CHAR(18) NULL ,
    articlesCharset      CHAR(18) NULL ,
    articlesHeaders      CHAR(255) NULL ,
    articlesTransferEncoding VARCHAR2(12) NULL ,
    articlesCacheControl VARCHAR2(12) NULL ,
    articlesContentType  VARCHAR2(12) NULL ,
    articlesPostedDate   DATE NULL ,
    articlesExpireDate   DATE NULL ,
    articlesSetCookie    VARCHAR2(128) NULL ,
    articlesDomain       VARCHAR2(64) NULL ,
    articlesServer       VARCHAR2(24) NULL ,
    articlesPragma       VARCHAR2(128) NULL ,
    urlFrontierURL       VARCHAR2(128) NULL ,
CONSTRAINT  XPK_ARTICLES PRIMARY KEY (articlesTitle))
TABLESPACE project_tablespace
STORAGE (INITIAL 8192 NEXT 8192 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 150000 );
```

Comment: Does Oracle not provide a nicer means of importing XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the data file columns have different lengths than table?

That error can happens because you are trying to insert char data which is bigger than 4000 characters long

Comment: Makes sense - all should match or be shorter than the destination.  Not being from an Oracle background, I assumed LONG meant '64-bit'.  :)